# How to click on radio button(I read previous questions) python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, radio-button

I have the code

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" id="grupo1" name="grupo1" name="ControlGroupSearchView2$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView2$RadioButtonMarketStructure" value="OneWay" />
    <label>One-way</label>
</div>
```

And I tried what other suggested to use

```
args["OW"] = "input[type='radio'][value='OneWay']"

WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, args["OW"])))

self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector(self.args["OW"]).click()
```

but I get error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

since it doesn't find the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there are no `iframe` elements on the page.

What I found working for radiobuttons is to click the corresponding `label` and not the `input`:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10)
one_way = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//label[. = 'One-way']")))
one_way.click()
```

Comment: if i dont have a label is it possible to click somehow on the input?

Comment: @DorAlt if you want to click that `input` based on the label text: `//label[. = 'One-way']/preceding-sibling::input`